# WPF Prism cannot find GetModuleCatalog(), method not found to override

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In the `Prism` samples there are a method with `GetModuleCatalog` name.

I want override this method in the `BootStrapper` class of my `WPF` application but when i write the following code

```
protected override  IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
{
    // SOME CODES
}
```

I get this error:

> No suitable method found to override

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `GetModuleCatalog()` is replaced with `CreateModuleCatalog()`. So we must change our code to this one:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    // SOME CODES
}
```